# success attribute unable to fire in View

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js

I am learning Backbone JS these days, below is the code unable to fire '**success**' in '**EditUser**'

please tell me what changes I need to do?

**Below code is combined code:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="edit-user-template">
        <form class="edit-user-form" method="POST">
            <legend>Create New User</legend>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
            <label>Age</label>  
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
            <hr/>
            <input type="submit" value="Create User" />
        </form>
</script>



var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: 'api/users'
})



var EditUser =  Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            events:{
                'submit .edit-user-form':'saveUser'
            },
            saveUser : function(e){
                var user = new User();
                user.save({firstName: $('#firstname').val() ,lastName: $('#lastname').val() ,age: $('#age').val() },    
                    {
                     success :  function(user){
                        console.log('INSIDE SUCCESS..')
                        router.navigate('',{trigger:'true'});
                    }
                });
            },
            render: function(){
                var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html());
                this.$el.html(template);
            }
})



@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public User create(User user) {
    return dao.create(user);
}



public User create(User user) {
Connection c = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
    ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    new String[] { "ID" });

    ps.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
    ps.setString(2, user.getLastName());
    ps.setInt(3, user.getAge());

    ps.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
    // Update the id in the returned object. This is important as this value must be returned to the client.
    int id = rs.getInt(1);
    user.setId(id);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionHelper.close(c);
    }
return user;
}
```

I already searched in google, but still not working their suggestions. Hope someone would clear me this issue

**UPDATE:**

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you put the codes for `User` class as well? is it a `XmlRootElement`?

Comment: @ChinKang Hey, i just kepted class User above too.. So, XmlRootElement for class User mandatory? if yes, why?

Comment: It was my random guess. My direction was, if you're using Jersey, without enable the `JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING`, you will need to mark the class to be a `XmlRootElement` or else the parser will not able to map the value object properly. For further checking, can you verify from the browser devtool, to check the POST returned a valid JSON object?

Comment: Is it that you are able to reach the server but only the success / error callbacks aren't being invoked?

Comment: add error callback and check if it fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saveUser method in EditUser view is not overriding the default behaviour of the submit event.

Try this :

```js
saveUser : function(e){
  // This will prevent the form from submitting normally.
  e.preventDefault();
  var user = new User();
  user.save(
    {
      firstName: $('#firstname').val() 
      ,lastName: $('#lastname').val() 
      ,age: $('#age').val() 
    },
    {
      success :  function(user){
        console.log('INSIDE SUCCESS..')
        router.navigate('',{trigger:'true'});
      }
     }
  );
}
```